# Apache redirect to a port and mask the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have one web server running two sites on different ports.
IE: server:8081 and  server:8083
I setup two DNS records and pointed it to “my server”

Dev.server.com and Pre.server.com

I would like Dev.server.com to redirect to server:8083 but mask the URL to always stay Dev.server.com and Pre.server.com to redirect to server:8081 but mask the URL to always stay pre.server.com

If I set them up like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http:// Dev.server.com
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / http://server:8083
ProxyPassReverse / http://server:8083
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http:// Pre.server.com
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / http://server:8081
ProxyPassReverse / http://server:8081
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything routes to the Dev instance and nothing makes it to the Pre instance

I have it set like this;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http:// Dev.server.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.server\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// Dev.server.com:8083$1 [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pre\.server\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pre. server.com:8081$1 [R]
</VirtualHost>
Listen 0.0.0.0:8083
Listen 0.0.0.0:8081
<VirtualHost *:8083>
ServerName dev. server.com
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / http:// server.com:8083/jde/owhtml/
ProxyPassReverse / http:// server.com:8083/jde/owhtml/
Oc4jMount /jde HTML_DV_8083
Oc4jMount /jde/* HTML_DV_8083
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8081>
ServerName pre.server.com
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass / http:// server.com:8081/jde/owhtml/
ProxyPassReverse / http:// server.com:8081/jde/owhtml/
Oc4jMount /jde HTML_PY_8081
Oc4jMount /jde/* HTML_PY_8081
</VirtualHost>
```

This works perfectly for the routing but does not mask the URL. It adds the port to the URL witch we do not want to happen.

Anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have spaces everywhere that don't belong? e.g. after `http://`

Comment: that was just a typo replacing the real server names.

Answer (score 1):

You want your reverse proxy to happen in your port 80 vhost. Because you're using mod_rewrite *to redirect the browser to* URLs like `http://Dev.server.com:8083/`, that's what the browser will see. You just need 2 vhosts on port 80:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName dev.server.com

  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass / http://server.com:8083/jde/owhtml/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://server.com:8083/jde/owhtml/
  Oc4jMount /jde HTML_DV_8083
  Oc4jMount /jde/* HTML_DV_8083
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName pre.server.com

  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass / http://server.com:8081/jde/owhtml/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://server.com:8081/jde/owhtml/
  Oc4jMount /jde HTML_PY_8081
  Oc4jMount /jde/* HTML_PY_8081
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that the "ServerName" is `dev.server.com` and `pre.server.com`, and **not** `http:// Dev.server.com` with a space following the scheme and ://. Because `http:// Dev.server.com` isn't going to be the hostname you're going to visit, apache defaults everything to the first vhost. This is probably why your second attempt works, because both dev and pre default to the first vhost since nothing matches on port 80.

Comment: Thank you Jon for the reply. That didn't work though. it still routed to the first vhost. I reversed the order of the vhosts and then everything routed to the one at the top of the list

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the fact that the "servername" and the dns name are different? 

    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pre.jde.DOMAINNAME.com
    ProxyPass / http://SERVERNAME:8081/jde/owhtml/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://SERVERNAME:8081/jde/owhtml/
    Oc4jMount /jde HTML_PY_8081
     Oc4jMount /jde/* HTML_PY_8081
    </VirtualHost>